# Where have my questions/answers gone which I wrote on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I was recently going through my profile on Meta Stack Overflow and found that all of my posts (questions/answers) and even my comments are gone, I mean I can't see them in my profile. Were they deleted for some reason? Any clean up activity?

Comment: Perhaps you were looking for https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/191332/mistu4u instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters They never posted to meta.SE since the split, FYI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The old Meta Stack Overflow site was moved to https://meta.stackexchange.com several years back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).

When SO's meta went from being another main site whose topic was "Meta Stack Overflow content" to an actual per site meta (which has a lot of technical implications, see the link for details). Your old content is there:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/191332/mistu4u